# What is formal comp. sci. name of this language property?

Tags: objective-c, ruby, theory

As a self-taught programmer, my definitions get fuzzy sometimes.

I'm very used to C and ObjC. In both of those your code must adhere to the language "structure". You can only do certain things in certain places. As an example, this is an error:

```
// beginning of file
NSLog(@"Hello world!"); // can't do this

@implementation MYClass
...
@end
```

However, in Ruby, anything you put anywhere is executed as the interpreter goes through it. So what is the difference between Ruby and Objective-C that allows this?

At first I thought it was that one was interpreted and the other compiled. Then I read some SO posts and the wikipedia definitions. Interpreted or compiled is a property of the implementation not the language. So that would mean there could (theoretically) be an interpreted implementation of Objective-C? In that case, the fact that a statement cannot be outside the implementation can't be a property of compiled languages, and vice-versa if there was a compiled implementation of Ruby. Or am I wrong in assuming that different implementations of a language would work the same way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby hides lots of stuff.

Ruby is OO like C++, Objective C and Java, and has `main` like C but you don't see this.

`puts(42)` is method call. It is a method of the main object called `main`. You can see it by typing `puts self`.

If you don't specify the receiver (receiver.method()) Ruby will use the implicit one, `main`.

Check available methods:
`puts Object.private_methods.sort`

#### Why you can put everything anywhere?

C/C++ look for *main method* called `main`, and when C/C++ find it, it will be executed.
Ruby on other hands doesn't need `main` or other method/class to run first.

It execute code from the first line until it meet the end of file(or `__END__` on the separate line).

```
class Strongman
  puts "I'm the best!"
end
```

is just syntactic sugar for `Class.new` method:

```
Strongman = Class.new do
  puts "I'm the best!"
end
```

The same goes for 'module`.

`for` calls each and returns some kind of object. So you may think of it as something similar to method.

```
a = for i in 1..12; 42;end
puts a
# 1..12
```

In the end, it doesn't matter if it is method call or some kind of structure like C's `int main()`. *Programming language* decides what it should run first.

Comment: Your answer and @tadman's are the basically the same. But what explains the fact that I can put any arbitrary code *inside* of a class definition but outside of any methods and it gets executed as soon as the interpreter goes over it?

Comment: Wow... that is definitely a paradigm shift. Thank you.

Comment: @Shinigami Ruby is multi paradigmatic but here I explained OO-side of ruby only, so I don't think it's paradigm shift.Ruby is just very OO.

Comment: Yeah... obviously the concepts are not difficult to understand. But I would have never thought of a class in the way you rewrote `Strongman` - even though I already knew that a class is an instance of the Class class ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure there's a technical term for it, but in most programming languages the context of the statement is extremely important.

Ruby has a concept of a root or `main` context where code is allowed. Other scripting languages follow this convention, presumably made popular by languages like Perl which allowed for very concise programming.

This allows things like this to be a complete and valid program:

```
print "Hello world!\n"
```

In other languages you need to define an entry point, such as a `main` routine, that is executed instead. Arbitrary code is not really allowed at the top level, which instead is reserved for things like function, type, constant, structure and class definitions.

A language like Ruby has a lot of control over the order in which the code is executed. C, by comparison, is usually composed of separate source files that are then linked together, where there's no inherent order to the way things are linked. All the modules are simply assembled into the final library or executable. This is why the `main` entry point is required, it defines which function to run first.

In short, it boils down to syntax, context, and language design considerations.

Comment: But it's not just that standalone lines are executed. The reason this question came up was because I realized in Ruby, I can write a class, then inside the class (and outside of any methods) I can put any arbitrary code, and it's still executed. What explains that?

Comment: Once again, boils down to what kinds of statements are allowed in a given context, something that, in technical terms, is a restriction of the language syntax. Ruby is *unusually* liberal in that regard, where executable code is allowed inside class definitions to the point where `def`, `class` and `module` behave almost like methods. C++ allows *some* form of this, where you can have "executable" code being evaluated in the context of an assignment, but what sort of code is extremely limited, it must be an expression. In Ruby you're allowed to use blocks just about anywhere.

Comment: If you're more curious about how this all works on a very low level, look at the way compilers are constructed. Most languages have some kind of grammar, with the easiest to implement being context-free, such as LISP, and the hardest being extremely context sensitive, like Perl. Building your own toy language by writing a lexer and compiler is an interesting exercise that will make this a lot more clear as you'll have to define your grammar and implement a parser for it.

Comment: In short: Why can't I put executable code in the middle of my C++ class but I can in the middle of my Ruby class? Talk to [Bjarne](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bjarne_Stroustrup) and [Matz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukihiro_Matsumoto) about their design decisions.